# Why should we use environmental variables in node.js?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

While I can understand the benefit of using a `.env` file, what are the pros and cons (if any) of using them versus placing the values directly in the code? I've see many guides that explain how to use them, but never why should we use them. Are they considered a best practice? Should every production project use them?

```
# File: .env
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=rootz
DB_PASS=s1mpl3

# File: random_db.js
const db = require('db')
db.connect({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS
})
```

Comment: https://12factor.net/config

Comment: Please clarify what alternatives you are considering. Are you asking for pros and cons of `.env` files versus placing the values directly in the code? Or still using environment variables, but not in a `.env` file?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion Kyle. I will also check out that link jonr

Comment: So you can use version management without storing your credentials?

Comment: Do you want to compile a specific version of your application or write a specific env for every port it is deployed on?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Was this primarily adopted from ruby on rails or was it common elsewhere? PHP maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best practice not to include database configuration information directly in the code. Keeping these items in environment variables instead has the following benefits:

- It allows you to use different databases for different instances of the program. For example, to have a development and production instance of the same application
- It allows you to protect the database credentials. Putting these credentials in the source code might be an option for closed-source highly guarded code, but it's much easier to protect them if they are somewhere else
- It allows you to change the database configuration without changing the code. Perhaps you've decided to host your database somewhere else. It's nice to be able to do this without rebuilding the application

I'm sure there are other reasons that I am not thinking of right now, but these alone are enough to convince most people.